# If i switching from windows 10 to Ubuntu all partition are going to be erased?

Tags: partitioning

Currently i am using win10 and i have 4 partition on my disk . Windows (c),(d),(e),(f) like this. If I select the option which "erases everything in your disk", maybe its first one during installation than what happen? Is only my window(c) partition erased or will all my partitions c,d,e,f be erased?

Comment: If you select to install on the disk, ALL partitions will be replaced, not only one. Disk means a physical disk.

Comment: I always use '*Something Else*' (or '*Manual Partitioning*' if Lubuntu and `calamares` installer) and partition exactly what I want (selecting 'format' or no-format as required). You can have exactly what you want, but backup first as we all make careless or unintentional mistakes.

Comment: "disk" means whole disk. If it meant partition then it would say "partition."

Comment: Microsoft is the one that confuses "drive" with partition. A d: drive can be a second partition on first drive or sda2 in Linux or a d: drive can be the first partition on second drive or sdb1. Linux separates drive & partition so you know which is which. If converting to Linux best not to keep NTFS partitions. They require maintenance like chkdsk or defrag that you cannot do from Linux. Best to have full back up of Windows & make a Windows repair/recovery drive if keeping NTFS partitions.

Answer (score 2):

The option "Erase everything in your disk" does what it promises. It erases everything on disk. Thus, all partitions on that specific disk (which in Windows will represent additionsal "Drives", will be erased.

If you do not want anything erased, then have Ubuntu install in the free space. You can make free space yourself by deleting partitions you do not anymore need. This can be done from within Windows, or using a partition editor such as GParted. GParted is available in the Ubuntu version that you can start up from the live CD or USB.

Answer (score 0):

If you select "Replace Windows with Ubuntu" all Windows partitions will be removed. You will lose all your data.

You can keep Windows and install Ubuntu, or select "something else" and manully select where to install Ubuntu.